# Wordpress - How to set my Posts Page as Home Page

Tags: wordpress, posts

I have several static pages like: Home, About, Contact etc. These are displayed as Menus at the top.

I want to display my posts in the Front Landing Page.

But under: Settings> Readings - when i choose Front Page and Posts Page as same, i get a warning that Front and Posts Page cannot be same, and it does not work either.

I am using the Enterprise Theme, but the same is case with other themes also.

**How to set the Front (main) Page as Posts Page?**

Comment: see http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-set-home-page-and-posts-page-the-same

Comment: Tamil Selvan> I am not self-hosting Wordpress, so can i still create a template, edit .php etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show your posts on the start page, just select the option "Your latest posts" instead of "A static page" at "Front page displays" in the "Reading" ("Settings" -> "Reading") options.

[image: Wordpress Front page reading options]

But: Sometimes it depends on your theme. But on the most themes this works.

**Update:**

It's also possible to add this first page with posts into the menu. Just select in "Appearance" -> "Menus" in the widget "Pages" the tab "View all" and select Home and add it to your menu.

[image]

Comment: TIUNDER> Yes i did try that, but i want my posts to show under the first Page (which is a menu too).

Comment: @Jasper You can still select the start page for the menu. Just select in "Appearance" -> "Menus" in the left at the "pages" the tab "view all". There you will see a menu point "Home: Home", which you can drag into your menu.

Comment: @Jasper I updated my answer with a screenshot for the menu

Comment: TIIUNDER> Fantastic, it worked. Any idea, how can i update wordpress, .php files - just buying paid version is enough (no self hosting) OR, do i need to self-host?

Comment: @Jasper Great that it works now :) But I don't know the possibilities of a non-self-hostet Wordpress, sorry.